# Faulty button makes the phonecall before pressing it

Tags: iphone, xcode, button

The code works but the app is calling the string without the press of the button. As soon as I reach the particular page of the app, it is bypassing everything (Other buttons, map views, etc) and makes the call...

The code I'm using is:

```
   - (void)loadNo2 {
        UIButton *no2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [no2 setTitle:@"2108642700" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [no2 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [no2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [no2 setFrame:CGRectMake(84, 260, 152, 31)];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://1234567890"]];
        [self addSubview:no2];
    }
```

What is wrong with it???

Answer (score 3):

This line brings up the dialog to dial

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://1234567890"]];
```

You didn't add it as a button action -- you are just calling it.

Replace that line with this:

```
  [no2 addTarget:self 
          action:@selector(onNo2Touch) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And add this:

```
-(void) onNo2Touch:(id) sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://1234567890"]];
}
```

Comment: it seems that I need to correct something in the main.m file #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"Mods_HairAppDelegate");
 [pool release];
 return retVal;
}

Comment: You don't need to make any changes to your main() function.  That is something you should never need to change.  Lou's answer here is correct.

Comment: it actually solve the initial problem but now crashes... the problem seems to be in this particular line of the main.m:     int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"example");

Comment: The crash is probably unrelated.  I wrote this for debugging crashes http://loufranco.com/blog/files/Understanding-EXC_BAD_ACCESS.html

Comment: Lou thank you very much for the support. I must see now why it crashes. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've called the openURL from the method that creates the button. 
You should put the call to UIApplication sharedApp... (i.e.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://1234567890"]];`
) 
inside the method called from the action (that is mapped to the button) .